# Creating 1 hour delay with 89C51 micro controller

Tags: microcontroller, timer, atmel, assembly, delay

I am writing an Assembly Program function for 89C51 which can create one hour delay. I can't  use any other micro controller as only 89c51/52 is available locally. So I am stuck here because even when I set `R5 to #255` the maximum delay I can create this way is only 2 minutes. As my knowledge is somehow weak in Assembly C I think there may be an easier way to do this. Please help me how I can I do this with Assembly C.

Here is my code with timer:

```
 DELAY:
  MOV R5,#24
  AGAIN:
     MOV TMOD,#01
     MOV TL0,#0
     MOV TH0,#0
     SETB TR0
     JNB TF0,$
     CLR TR0
     CLR TF0
      DJNZ R5,AGAIN
     RET
```

Code for doing it without timers with loops:

```
DELAY2:
      MOV R5,#12
      L4:MOV R6,#255
      L3:MOV R7,#255
      DJNZ R7,$
      DJNZ R6,L3
      DJNZ R5,L4
```

Please Help!

Comment: What's the problem you are having>

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The problem is that the maximum delay generated is 2 minute even when I set R5 to #255. I want to know that how can I create one hour delay?

Comment: "I can't use any other micro controller as only 89c51/52 is available locally." -- Where are you, locked in the basement of the 89c5x factory?

Comment: You just asked essentially this same question two days ago: [Maximum attainable delay with Micro controller](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23743/maximum-attainable-delay-with-micro-controller).  What was wrong with the answers to that question?

Comment: @tcrosley the previous question was about theory this question is about the practical code that do it in assembly C. Anyhow thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem you are having? Did you write this code or have you copied it from somewhere else and are trying to make it work?

Considering the code below. Does it work when you run it? (This should be identical to your code.)

[image]

The answer was:

- yes it works but it creates a much lesser delay.
- I want to create one hour delay. ... I need some help/hints to modify the function so that it can generate one hour delay.

Let's see if that makes sense.
 The inner loop decrements R7 - always set to 255 on entry.
  This is called 255 times by the R6 loop
 This is called 255 times by the R5 loop

L2 loop R7 is 255 decrements
 L3 is 255 x (decrement, jump)
 L4 is 255 x (decrement, jump)

Even treated simplistically as if each loop was a single instruction.
 Operations = 255 x 255 x 255 = 16,581,385 ~= 16 million instructions.
 As this produces a 2 minute delay there would be 8 million instructions/minute 
 As we actually have a jump and a decrement in most cases we'd expect 2 or 3 cycles or intstructions. So maybe 24 million instructions per minute  depending on the instruction. That's only about300,000 insructions per second. That sounds horrendously slow - but see below.

So, the is not able to create a delay which is nit long enough.

If you added another loop outside the existing one you'd expect about 255 x 2 minutes  = 510 minutes = 8.5 hours.

So - add one more loop.
 Fine tune delays to suit.

Comment: yes it works but it creates a much lesser delay. I want to create one hour delay. I wrote that code. I have heard that one hour delay can be genearated with 89c51. I need some help/hints to modify the function so that it can generate one hour delay.

Comment: So nice of you to consider helping me.

Comment: wow thanksss!!! so I have to use R4 and R3 for other two loops I am going to check it right now...

Comment: Whoops - you said 2 minutes - I said 2 seconds !!!. So one more loop is enough.

Comment: ok :) I got the hint from your answer Now I can do it

Answer (score 3):

First, lots of micros are available anywhere in the world.  Most distributors will ship anywhere.  I'm in Massachussetts, but when I buy Microchip PICs the get shipped to me from Thailand.

Second, regardless of the microcontroller, any amount of delay can be created by nesting loops.  You have already said you can create a 2 minute delay.  So write a loop that calls the 2 minute delay 30 times and you have a 1 hour delay.

Third, a busy-wait like what you are doing is a very inefficient, inaccurate, and difficult to maintain way of making a delay.  If you ever want the micro to do something else during the delay period, you would have to redo the whole delay mechanism.  It also leaves the micro running the whole time.  A better way for most applications, especially for long delays like this, is to use a timer to get some fixed period, then count the fixed periods.  For example, a 1 ms periodic interrupt is often convenient for timing in a micro.  You could simply count 3.6M 1ms ticks, or you could derive slower ticks from it and then count those.  Often the slower ticks are useful for other things anyway.  I often make 10ms, 100ms, and 1s ticks from the 1ms ticks.  In this case you could count 3600 1s ticks.

Sometimes power consumption is important.  In that case you use a slow oscillator, like a 32768 Hz watch crystal, to wake up the processor every second or whatever.  Many micros have drivers for such crystals built in.  Sometimes using the built-in watchdog timer to wake the processor periodically is good enough if you don't need high accuracy.

Remember that each bit in a clock tick counter doubles the maximum time it can count.  Processors have lots and lots of bits.  You can easily make a counter that will outlast the silicon it is running on.