# Maximum delay generation in STM32F207

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum attainable delay with Micro controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23743/maximum-attainable-delay-with-micro-controller)

I need to generate delays for one hour, two hours, etc. What is the maximum possible delay that can be generated in the STM32F207 controller?

Also, what is the procedure for the implementation using any of the timers available in the STM32F207 controller?

Comment: I might look into the details of the STM32F207's timers if I can lay my hands on the datasheet. The ST website stinks. You can't get at any document from within Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

*Any* microcontroller can create *any* delay. If a timer overflows increment a counter. If that counter overflow, increment another one. 128 bits is infinity.